# Google Cloud Logging VS Datastore for logging app activity

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to log user activity in my appengine app, which will server both web and mobile users. I'm having a problem deciding which google product I should store the activities to. Two options I'm considering are (Fairly new to both of these):

- Google Cloud Datastore as kinds (I think it's a different lingo for tables)
- Google Cloud logging as JSON

Price-wise, it seems like Google Cloud logging is cheaper at $0.50/GiB(one time charge for the amount logged) and $0.01/GiB per month, whereas Google Cloud Datastore charge for Read, write, delete + $0.18/GiB/month of storage.

Interface wise, It seems easier to use Cloud Datastore during debugging process. I still haven't gotten a hang of Log explorer yet.

Both have the option to export the data out to CSV.

Which one is recommended for the purpose of activity logging in the long run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging), it is the best for logging any app activity for your application and Google Cloud as it designed for this kind of requirement. For long terms, you can [configure](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#custom-retention) your [Cloud Logging retention period](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods) to retain your Logs up to **3650 days** or **10 years**. For pricing, the data retention will be priced at **$0.01/GiB** per month above default retention periods(**30 days**).